# Cannot load JSON to MongoDB, Becase of MongoDB specific notation

Tags: python, json, mongodb, ijson

I have a huge JSON file originally from MongoDB.

The file contains several MongoDB types, such as:

```
 "_id" : ObjectId("55a3490924012c2ab7a46f76"),
```

```
"year" : NumberInt(1975),
```

Because of them, I failed to load it into MongoDB database by `mongoimport`:

```
Failed: invalid JSON input. Position: 17. Character: O
```

Note the "Character: O" above is the first 'O' of 'ObjectID'.

I cannot use ijson Python Package neither:

```
import ijson
filepath = 'bigdata.publication.json'
f=open(filepath,'r',encoding="utf-8")
for id in ijson.items(f,'url'):
    print(id)
```

error message: `ijson.backends.python.UnexpectedSymbol: Unexpected symbol 'O' at 15`.

Is there any other way to parse the JSON file?

Comment: I'll mention the obvious - the extended JSON format used by MongoDB isn't standard JSON, so no standard tools are going to be able to parse it.  MongoImport should work though.  It looks like the export was done with older versions of the tools (https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/mongodb-extended-json-v1/) via Mongo Shell Mode - maybe re-try the export with mongoexport to force Strict Mode?

Comment: Or try with the --legacy flag on mongoimport https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongoimport/#cmdoption-mongoimport-legacy